# Sending data from a express post request

Tags: ajax, node.js, express

I'm playing around with Node.js and Express.

I've got something like this on my front end:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: window.location.href,
        dataType: "jsonp", // expecting cross domain requests later
        data: {"url":url}, // this is not relevant for this question
        success: function(data){
             console.log("data received");
        }
});
```

And here is my backend for express,

```
app.post("/", function(req, res){
   res.send("Hello");    
}
```

However, the "Hello" doesn't get sent over. Is there a different syntax for sending data over when there is a post request? Am I missing something here?

Comment: How do you know what is it isn't being sent?

Comment: @Amit Nothing is being sent to the console, as it should on 'success'

Comment: You have a typo in your `app.post`. It should end with `})`, not just `}`. Not sure if this will solve your problem, though.